# add dynamic input tag with unique id through datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to create the input tag depending on the rows but I couldn't able to add unique id for each input field.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#jsontable').dataTable();  //Initialize the datatable
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php?method=fetchdata',
        data: 'json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(s){
            oTable.fnClearTable();
            for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                oTable.fnAddData([s[i]['productTitle'],s[i]['sku'],s[i]['name'],s[i]['pricePerUnit'],s[i]['code'],'<input type="text" id="quantity"+i+/>',]);
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
           console.log(e.responseText); 
        }
    });
});
```

I am highlighting which field should be dynamic.

> oTable.fnAddData([s[i]['productTitle'],s[i]['sku'],s[i]['name'],s[i]['pricePerUnit'],s[i]['code'],' type="text" **id="quantity"+i+/>**',]);

please give any suggestions.

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `'<input type="text" id="quantity"+i+/>'` to `'<input type="text" id="quantity'+i+'"/>'`